# Question about finding a limit with limit arithmetics

Tags: calculus, limits

$lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{4n^2}{(2n+1)(2n-1)})^{1-n^2}$

When I simplfy it I get: $\frac{1-4n^2}{(1-4n^2)^{n^2}}$

Now is it enough to use limit arithmetics on the denominator as if it's $\frac1{x^n}$ to show that it goes to 0 ?

Note: we can't use logs/lns/derive/integrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplification is wrong as $$\frac{4n^2}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}=\frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}=1+\frac1{4n^2-1}$$

$$\implies \left(\frac{4n^2}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}\right)^{1-n^2}=\left(1+\frac1{4n^2-1}\right)^{1-n^2}=\left(\left(1+\frac1{4n^2-1}\right)^{4n^2-1}\right)^{\frac{1-n^2}{4n^2-1}}$$

As $n\to\infty, 4n^2-1\to\infty$ and we know $\displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1m\right)^m=e$

and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-n^2}{4n^2-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{n^2}-1}{4-\frac1{n^2}}=-\frac14$

Comment: That was pretty amazing. So as I understand it the limit of the expression is $e^{-\frac14}$ right ?
I also didn't know that we can do a limit to the exponents.

Comment: @GinKin, your are right. Grasp some the basic formula of limits preferably along with the proof